# Pandas reading CSVs and filtering dataframe based on filedate

Tags: python, date, csv, pandas

I'm trying to read a bunch of CSV-files into a single pandas dataframe. Some of the CSVs have data for multiple dates. I want only the data from each CSV that has a date equal to the modification date of each file.

Here is my current attempt:

```
import os
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import glob as glob

path =r'C:xxx' 
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
frame = pd.DataFrame()
def modification_date(filename):
   t = os.path.getmtime(filename)
   return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
   df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None, header=0)
   df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATE"], format='%Y-%m-%d')
   filedate = modification_date(allFiles)
   df = df[(df["DATE"] == filedate)]
   list_.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(list_)
frame.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

This fails because the loop here creates a list of modification dates (since the folder contains many CSV's) that the function modification_date can't handle. Error is: "TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found"

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to modify this so each CSV is evaluated separately but can't seem to get far.

Comment: Why are you doing `filedate = modification_date(allFiles)` instead of `filedate = modification_date(file_)`?

Comment: Hah, this was the problem. Thanks for a fresh/sharp pair of eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

fmask = 'C:/Temp/.data/aaa/*.csv'

all_files = glob.glob(fmask)

# returns file's modification date (the time part will be truncated)
def get_mdate(filename):
    return (pd.to_datetime(os.path.getmtime(filename), unit='s')
              .replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0))

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, parse_dates=['DATE'])
                  .query('DATE == @get_mdate(@f)')
                for f in all_files
               ],
               ignore_index=True)
```

Test:

1.csv:         `# modification date: 2016-07-07`

```
DATE,VAL
2016-07-06,10
2016-07-06,10
2016-07-05,10
2016-07-07,110
2016-07-07,110
```

2.csv:         `# modification date: 2016-07-05`

```
DATE,VAL
2016-07-06,1
2016-07-06,1
2016-07-05,1
2016-07-07,11
2016-07-07,11
```

Result:

```
In [208]: %paste
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, parse_dates=['DATE'])
                  .query('DATE == @get_mdate(@f)')
                for f in all_files
               ],
               ignore_index=True)
## -- End pasted text --

In [209]: df
Out[209]:
        DATE  VAL
0 2016-07-07  110
1 2016-07-07  110
2 2016-07-05    1
```